# Report that can show all the changes in the custom list list?

Tags: list, custom

I made a custom list in SP2010. I've used a three state workflow. The custom list is like a queue/ticket management tool for us. Is there a way for me to be able to extract a report so that I can see all the changes made? Like new items, changes made in each item? I tried the Custom reports in Audit log reports but it doesn't show the things I need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Setup Audit Logging in SharePoint 2010 to accomplish this. Visit this [blog](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.in/2013/07/audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2013.html) to see how this is accomplished.

Detailed information can be obtained from this given informative reference : [View audit log reports](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131?CorrelationId=c0d2edd7-b2b8-43ec-ad07-24bf7ad47d08&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102039795)

Moreover, if you still unable to see audit log reports, You may also give a shot to [solution](https://www.lepide.com/lepideauditor/sharepoint-auditing.html) which assits to track every critical changes reports into real time even at granular level.